# I want to develop php websites in laravel. Where can i find the relevent projects on it for practice?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to start a project on laravel but i dont know the abc of laravel framework. Can anyone provide the link from where i can learn it?

Comment: Best way to start is from Tutorials.. Here check out.. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Comment: Just find tutorials on the web, there is also a book by Matt Staufer about it, i learned from this book. He explains the Laravel components quite well and it is easily understandable for someone who has already programmed in normal PHP, if you have never experienced anything with PHP i recommend watching youtube video's on laravel, or Laracasts.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many resource . the best is

1. laravel documentation -  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4
2. laracasts.com
3. youtube videos

Answer (score 0):

try [laracasts.com](http://laracasts.com)

It's a tutorial website, and is probably one of the best sources for learning laravel.